# Drupal 7: restrict access by path

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I need to restrict various sections of my site. I would like to do this by restricting access to various subpaths. The Path Access module doesn't actually do this.

Can you suggest any mechanism that would allow for the restriction of something like:

members-area/editors/* 
restricted to only users with 'editor' role.

Maybe there's a way to do this with rules? I've tried, but can't find one.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You'll need a custom module for this, it's not too difficult. This would be the crux of it:

```
// Implements hook_init()
function mymodule_init() {
  $restrictions = mymodule_get_restrictions();
  global $user;
  foreach ($restrictions as $path => $roles) {
    // See if the current path matches any of the patterns provided.
    if (drupal_match_path($_GET['q'], $path)) {
      // It matches, check the current user has any of the required roles
      $valid = FALSE;
      foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if (in_array($role, $user->roles)) {
          $valid = TRUE;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (!$valid) {
        drupal_access_denied();
      }
    }
  }
}

function mymodule_get_restrictions() {
  // Obviously this data could come from anywhere (database, config file, etc.)
  // This array will be keyed by path and contain an array of allowed roles for that path
  return array(
    'members-area/editors/*' => array('editor'),
    'another-path/*' => array('editor', 'other_role'),
  );
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks for this, I will try it out. The only problem is that I'm not supposed to be using any custom code for my current project.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Content Access module](http://drupal.org/project/content_access)? You might be able to squeeze what you're trying to do out of that :-)

Answer (score 0):

> The Path Access module gives site administrators an additional layer
>   of access control to all pages of a Drupal site.

http://drupal.org/project/path_access